# how to implement CAB for multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `ActionBarActivity` that has two tabs. I have implemented a `ActionMode.Callback` in tab1(fragment1). Now i want to implement it in tab2(fragment2) as well. The problem is that the tab1 Contextual action bar is active even after i swipe to tab2. This means a CAB is meant to be implemented for an activity, not for specific fragment.

So what is the approach to take to have different CABs in two fragments hosted in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreateActionMode` callback save a reference of the `ActionMode` in your fragment, and then in your fragment's `onPause` you can finish your action. Example:

```
protected class MultiChoiceModeListener implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        ConversationFragment.this.actionMode = mode;
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete_conversation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {  
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        ConversationFragment.this.actionMode = null;
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (actionMode != null) {
        actionMode.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: the `onPause()` is not executed when moving to another tab(fragment)

Comment: That's strange. Then, I assume that you have a listener when the active tab is changed inside your activity. You could do the same thing there, using callbacks.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. I implemented popup context menus in my second fragment for now. Will definitely try your idea next time.